# Time depending images as input in a CNN

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

I'll try my best to be understood, thank you for reading.

So this is the problem :

I'm asked to predict cancer on X-ray as early as possible. The dataset is composed of images in this form  img_patient1_week1,img_patient1_week2, img_patient1_week3
and that for a lot of different patient.
Some of them did develop cancer and we can see the tumor growing with the weeks, and some of them didn't.

I usually train a CNN for classification with images but here it's quite different since I want to predict if something is about to happen for a new patient as early as possible (week 1 or week 2) by detecting patterns while training.

Maybe I should go for a CNN and a Recurrent Neural Network to create a link between the images of the same patient ?

So I don't know how to do this or if it's the right way of handling it.

Thank you for your help,

b.

Comment: Your approach is the correct approach to solve this problem. Treat the series of images as frames of a video.